# Android KitKat 4.4 TalkBack view refresh issue

Tags: android, android-listview, refresh, android-4.4-kitkat, talkback

I'm running my app on an Android 4.4.2 (KitKat) device.
My app has a ListView. 
When I add the last item to the list view, it shows some content, and about 5 seconds later, it changes (loads a different view to that specific list item).

While TalkBack is on -

If, in that 5 seconds window, I click on the last item - the TalkBack marks it, reads it, and does not let the view change.

I do not have this issue on previous Android version.

Anyone knows why this happens? and if I can override this behavior?

Thanks!

PB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a direct solution.
I have solved the issue by overriding accessibility default behavior.
I removed the mark around the view and kept only the reading part.

This is the code I used:

```
view.setAccessibilityDelegate(new AccessibilityDelegate() {
            @Override
            public boolean performAccessibilityAction(View host, int action, Bundle args) {
                //call super to perform the action
                boolean ret = super.performAccessibilityAction(host, action, args);
                //call super with remove-focus action to remove the mark around the view
                super.performAccessibilityAction(host, AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLEAR_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, args);
                return ret;
            }
         });
```